# How to create an application Node.js in bluemix

Tags: json, node.js, ibm-cloud, watson-conversation, watson

I built my workspace so I have the JSON file and I want to create an application like the example of the car dashboard. I don't want to waste time to write HTML and CSS code so I want to use the code of the car dashboard example and just change the JSON file. How can I do so?

Comment: Can you provide a link to this car dashboard example?

Comment: https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/car-dashboard here

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the [Car Dashboard example here](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/car-dashboard), you could follow the instructions on deploying the app (there are some listed), then change the car_workshop.json file and then use the *Import Workspace* to upload your version of the file.

Comment: thank you for your response! what I did is that I pushed the application in bluemix! then I created a workspace and I modified the code (.env and manifest.yml) with the worspace_id, username and password and I pushed BUT I have the same error: